# R- How many times does a text value show across in a row?

Tags: regex, r, text, split, addition

I have a my data in a dataframe as follows:

```
someName    someID  1                  2                  3
A           1       T7(P),M6(O),S6(P)  T7(P),M6(O),S6(P)  T7(P),M6(O),S6(P),S7(P)
B           2       S4(P)              S4(P)              NA
C           3       S1(P),Q9(D)        S1(P),Q9(D)        S16(P),Q9(D)
D           4       S5(P),C7(C),S4(P)  S4(P),C7(C),S4(P)  S5(P),C7(C),S14(P)
E           5       S18(P)             S18(P)             S18(P)
F           6       S1(P)              NA                 S1(P)
L           8       Z1(P)              NA                 NA
Z           9       NA                 NA                 Q100(P)
```

I would like to read across each row in my `df1` and find exact matches for split elements and count them.
Then display the total in a new column `cbind` to my `df1`.

For example in row `someName=A`, I would want to split the string in column 1,2,3 on commas and look for `T7(P)` which is found in all 3 so the sum would be 3. So is `S6(P)`. So the total would be `3+3=6` for `row A`. `(S7(P)` is ignored since it is not found in any other column).

I want to ignore any other item that does not have a `(P)`, so `M6(O)` is ignored.

`Row L` would have a total of 0, since it does not intersect any other columns.

So I could use the `apply` function to go row by row then split the columns by `,`

Then how can i do an intersect or match across the split values?

My `dput(df1)` is:

```
structure(list(someName = structure(1:8, .Label = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "L", "Z"), class = "factor"), someID = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L), `1` = c("T7(P),M6(O),S6(P)", "S4(P)", 
"S1(P),Q9(D)", "S5(P),C7(C),S4(P)", "S18(P)", "S1(P)", "Z1(P)", 
NA), `2` = c("T7(P),M6(O),S6(P)", "S4(P)", "S1(P),Q9(D)", "S4(P),C7(C),S4(P)", 
"S18(P)", NA, NA, NA), `3` = c("T7(P),M6(O),S6(P),S7(P)", NA, 
"S16(P),Q9(D)", "S5(P),C7(C),S14(P)", "S18(P)", "S1(P)", NA, 
"Q100(P)")), .Names = c("someName", "someID", "1", "2", "3"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here another approach using regular expression and `table`. The idea is to extract , from each row, elements having a certain pattern **[A-Z][0-9]+**(P) and count them if they are present more than once.

```
apply(dat,1,function(xx){
    tab <- table(unlist(regmatches(xx,gregexpr('[A-Z][0-9]+\\(P\\)',xx))))
    sum(tab[tab>1])
})
[ 1] 6 2 2 5 3 2 0 0
```

Comment: perfect! Thank you both for your code.i used cbind to add a column to my main data frame.

Answer (score 3):

An attempt, assuming your `data.frame` is called `test`:

```
# collapse and split them up
splts <- strsplit(apply(test[3:5],1,function(x) paste(x,collapse=",")),",")
# remove all the non (P) cases
splts <- mapply(function(x,y) x[y], splts, lapply(splts, function(x) grep("(P)",x,fixed=TRUE)))
# sum up those that appear more than once
test$sumtext <- sapply(splts,function(x) sum(table(x)[table(x)>1]))
```

Result:

```
> test[,c(1,2,6)]
  someName someID sumtext
1        A      1       6
2        B      2       2
3        C      3       2
4        D      4       5
5        E      5       3
6        F      6       2
7        L      8       0
8        Z      9       0
```